# TXT entrada UTF-8, salida TXT UTF-8. Netbeans -> Run -> archivos perfectos, usando el jar -> caracteres raros. ¿Qué puede ser?

Tags: java, utf-8, codificación, jar

Creé una aplicación que lee 2 archivos de texto(txt), en uno hay texto ruso y en el otro español. (Ambos txt en UTF-8)

Luego arma un solo txt con ambos textos. La salida del/los txt tambien es/son UTF-8.

Si el programa lo ejecuto en NetBeans IDE 8.2, la salida de los archivos txt es perfecta. Lo corra la cantidad de veces que lo corra es perfecta.

Si el programa lo creo en un Jar, a la hora de realizar la tarea los archivos txt me salen con caracteres raros.

NetBeans -> perfectos.
Jar compilado -> caracteres raros.

Para leer los txt uso BufferedReader y para escribir BufferedWriter(FileWriter).
De esta manera en NetBeans anda perfecto, en el Jar caracteres raros.

Probé usar la misma lectura y en escritura BufferedWriter -> OutputStreamWriter -> FileOutputStream StandardCharsets.UTF_8.
De esta manera en NetBeans anda perfecto y en el Jar caracteres DOBLEMENTE raros.

Siempre los archivos salen en UTF-8. (Acá adjunto parte de los textos según qué se usó)

```
File Writer en NetBeans IDE UTF-8:
# --- 0.13: Макс подходит к комнате Анны, дверь закрыта

    13.ka.0@4@<i>Обычно мама в это время отдыхает. Скорее всего, она ещё не спит. Оставить её в покое или войти?</i>|<i>Por lo general, mamá se relaja a esta hora del día. ¿Debería ingresar o debería dejarla en paz?</i>

OutputStreamWriter -> FileOutputStream en NetBeans IDE UTF-8:
# --- 0.13: Макс подходит к комнате Анны, дверь закрыта

    13.ka.0@4@<i>Обычно мама в это время отдыхает. Скорее всего, она ещё не спит. Оставить её в покое или войти?</i>|<i>Por lo general, mamá se relaja a esta hora del día. ¿Debería ingresar o debería dejarla en paz?</i>

File Writer en Jar UTF-8:
# --- 0.13: Мак�? подходит к комнате �?нны, дверь закрыта

    13.ka.0@4@<i>Обычно мама в �?то врем�? отдыхает. Скорее в�?его, она ещё не �?пит. О�?тавить её в покое или войти?</i>|<i>Por lo general, mamá se relaja a esta hora del día. ¿Debería ingresar o debería dejarla en paz?</i>

OutputStreamWriter -> FileOutputStream en Jar UTF-8:
ï»¿# --- 0.13: ÐœÐ°ÐºÑ� Ð¿Ð¾Ð´Ñ…Ð¾Ð´Ð¸Ñ‚ Ðº ÐºÐ¾Ð¼Ð½Ð°Ñ‚Ðµ Ð�Ð½Ð½Ñ‹, Ð´Ð²ÐµÑ€ÑŒ Ð·Ð°ÐºÑ€Ñ‹Ñ‚Ð°

    13.ka.0@4@<i>ÐžÐ±Ñ‹Ñ‡Ð½Ð¾ Ð¼Ð°Ð¼Ð° Ð² Ñ�Ñ‚Ð¾ Ð²Ñ€ÐµÐ¼Ñ� Ð¾Ñ‚Ð´Ñ‹Ñ…Ð°ÐµÑ‚. Ð¡ÐºÐ¾Ñ€ÐµÐµ Ð²Ñ�ÐµÐ³Ð¾, Ð¾Ð½Ð° ÐµÑ‰Ñ‘ Ð½Ðµ Ñ�Ð¿Ð¸Ñ‚. ÐžÑ�Ñ‚Ð°Ð²Ð¸Ñ‚ÑŒ ÐµÑ‘ Ð² Ð¿Ð¾ÐºÐ¾Ðµ Ð¸Ð»Ð¸ Ð²Ð¾Ð¹Ñ‚Ð¸?</i>|<i>Por lo general, mamÃ¡ se relaja a esta hora del dÃ­a. Â¿DeberÃ­a ingresar o deberÃ­a dejarla en paz?</i>
```

Mi problema es solamente usando el Jar, alguna manera de solucionar esto? o Saber que puede ser? 
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el Netbeans usa un método para leer/escribir los archivos. Leyendo el código y basándose en ciertas pautas.

Cuando el jar se ejecuta utiliza su propio método y usa el modo predeterminado del windows. Para evitar esto al compilar añadí la siguiente opción.

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar miescript.jar
```

Con eso se resuelve.